# log dates of most recent file with multiple folders

Tags: file, date, batch-file, logging

My folder\file structure is as follows:

```
C:\Folder1\Folder2\CustomerFolder\Files.7z
```

I've set an ftp server, so the structure is strange.  Anyway, within each customer folder there are around 10 files each.  I'd like to run a batch file creating a text file that would go into each customer folder and return the most recent file date (don't care about the name, need to know when the file was created).  The text file would appear as follows:

```
CustomerFolder1 - 1/1/2014
CustomerFolder2 - 12/3/2013
```

Here is what I have so far, the for /f is where I get stopped:

```
for /d %%D in ("C:\ftp\localuser\*") do (
    cd /d "%%D"
    for /f
```

Comment: Please put your root folder structure.

Comment: C:\ftp\localuser\customer1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=u:\ftp\localuser"
SET "spaces=                               "
(
 for /d %%D in ("%sourcedir%\*") do (
  pushd "%%D"
  SET "latest="
  FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d /o:-d') DO IF NOT DEFINED latest (
   SET latest=Y
   FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ("%%D") DO SET cdir=%%~nxq%spaces%
   FOR /f "tokens=1" %%t IN ("%%~ta") DO CALL ECHO %%cdir:~0,20%% - %%t
  )
  popd
 )
)>newfile.txt

TYPE newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

You'd need to tickle the length of the directoryname to suit your maximum and possibly the date - if it shows the dayname, then change `tokens=1` to `tokens=2`.

I've also changed the source directory name to suit my system. You'd need to fix that to suit yours.

Answer (score 1):

I created some code, but it is possible you'll need to play with date/time format on your computer. Also you can change the display information (add more echo lines).

```
@echo off 
SetLocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set "ftpuserdir=C:\ftp\localuser"
for /d %%D in (%ftpuserdir%\*) do (
    echo.|set /p some=%%D
    set found=0
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /TC /O-D /B /A-D "%%D\*" 2^>nul') do (
        if !found!==0 (
            for /f "tokens=*" %%z in ('dir "%%D\%%a" 2^>nul') do (
                echo %%z | find "%%a">nul
                if !errorlevel!==0 (
                    rem echo Last file=%%z
                    for /f "tokens=1,2,3,*" %%s in ('echo %%z') do (
                            echo  - %%s_%%t_%%u
                    )
                    echo.
                    set found=1
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Please let me know if you have questions on code. I know it is quite complicated but I did not manage to make is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

here is the modified code:

@echo off
SetLocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set "ftpuserdir=C:\csftp\localuser"
for /d %%D in (%ftpuserdir%*) do (
    echo.|set /p some=%%D
    set found=0
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /TC /O-D /B /A-D "%%D*" 2^>nul') do (
        if !found!==0 (
            for /f "tokens=*" %%z in ('dir "%%D\%%a" 2^>nul') do (
                echo %%z | find "%%a">nul
                if !errorlevel!==0 (
                    rem echo Last file=%%z
                    for /f "tokens=1,2,3,*" %%s in ('echo %%z') do (
                            echo %%D %%s>>1.txt

```
                )
               :: echo.
                set found=1
            )
        )
    )
)
```

)

Here is the screen result (I can't post a pic yet..)
C:\csftp\localuser\cs1234C:\csftp\localuser\cs34234C:\csftp\localuser\cs4387

it keeps going like that...

and the text file doesn't list everything, kinda skips around.. in the C:\csftp\localuser folder I have manybe 100 subfolders I need this file to go through.